# Running nested virtualization with EPT over shadow paging with qemu-kvm

Tags: qemu, virtualization, kvm, ept

I'm experimenting with nested virtualization and using qemu-kvm.
I'm trying to run nested virtualization with shadow paging in the guest-host and EPT in the nested guest. Is there any way to do it?

I was able to run shadow paging in the nested guest with EPT in the guest host, and shadow paging in the nested guest with the guest host using EPT by disabling ept in the kvm_intel kernel module. I tried to give qemu different flags to enable the cpu feature "vmx-ept" while it's disabled in the kernel module.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a software development question, but rather a question about how to use QEMU/KVM.